# CSS/HTML - Item Not Centered

Tags: html, css

I have an object that a while ago would be centered with an opacke box around it that would fade in. My problem is now the text is in the corner and the box is gone. I'm not sure why. Everything seems to line up the css positioning looks fine,ect. If someone could help me figure out why the item is no longered centered with a box around it that would be great. You can see an example [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10329732/portfolio/parallasx/index.html)(scroll down to the last slide, the contact me page)

You can see the css for the box and the css for the text below.

Text CSS:

```
#slide4 .contact{
     color: red;
     position: relative;
     font-size:70px;
     top: 30px;
     left: 36%;
}
#slide4 .contact1{
     color: rgba(51,51,51,.3);
     position: relative;
     font-size: 40px;
     top: 100px;
     left: 8%;
}
#slide4 .contact2{

    position: absolute;
    font-size: 40px;
    top: 140px;
    right: 21%;
        color: rgba(51,51,51,.3);
}
#slide4 .box{
        position:relative;
    width: 400px;
        height: 200x;
    padding-right: 25px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
        background: rgba(255,255,255,.9);
    top: 100px;
    left: 32%;
    opacity: 0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);
}
```

Box CSS:

```
    <div class="box">
    <span class="contact1">This is a test</span>
    <span class="contact2">This is a test</span></div>
    </div>
```

So let me summerize up my question one more time why is the box not being centered along with text that should have a nice font that is no longer there.

Comment: You have some problem in your css file. First in `#homeprofile` `height`is defined twice and `:` is missing on the first one. `#slide3 .text`have an extra `{`. `}`is missing for `a:visited`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When i do `Inspect Element` in Chrome, it doesn't find the `slide4` related CSS properties.
Update your CSS `style.css` as suggested below,

```
/******************************
 SLIDE 3 
*******************************/
#slide3{
    background-color:#b6c10b;
}
#slide3 .text{
    position: relative;
    top: 35px;
    left: 505px;
    font-size: 35px;
    color: rgba(51,51,51,0.3);opacity: .3;}    ~~> remove } as its extra

} 

a:link {color:#333333;
opacity: .3;}    
a:visited {color:#333333;    ~~> add } as its missing
a:hover {color:#333333;
opacity: .3;} 
a:active {color:#333333;
opacity: .3;}
```

Comment: @apples Is it working now? Did my answer help you? Please accept the answer.

Comment: kinda but i cant seem to find why only one of the this is a test is showing up see [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10329732/portfolio/Parallasx/index.html)

Comment: @apples The `This is Test` text is present. Give `background-color` to `contact2` and you will see it. The content of box is actually overflowing. Hope this helps.

Comment: @apples Also, for contact1 and contact2 decrease the value of `top` property and you will see the text get shifted in your box. Also fix the height of `box` as `200px` (Note px not x).

Comment: I don't know how these thing happen i left the project for about two weeks and these things happen it must have been when my brother opened the css and html file

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code, First I deleted last two sentences related to **opacity** in your .box{} section. And It worked.

Otherwise, change **opacity** of box to **1**.

Hope this will help.

Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

You got several errors in your posted code:

- The box height is missing px.
- The opacity settings don't show the box.
- You got an extra div in the markup
- slide is not part of the markup